# Can't pass enum in .Net 2.0 Web Service

Tags: c#, web-services, enums, windows-mobile

I'm developing for Windows Mobile and so have to use Web Services rather than WCF. I have a business object that I pass via the web service which works fine except for one property that is an enum. This value always appears on the server as the default value no matter what the client has set it to. Very confused :(

Here's the code in the business object defined on the server:

```
public enum TaskTypeEnum { GoodsReceipt, ImportCosting };

[Serializable, DataContractAttribute]
public class TaskContainer
{
    [DataMemberAttribute] 
    public TaskTypeEnum TaskType { get; set; }       
...
```

And here's the code on the client that sets this property:

```
var container = new TaskContainer();
container.TaskType = TaskTypeEnum.ImportCosting;
service.Save(container);
```

For some unknown reason when this "container" object gets to the server, the TaskType property is always set to GoodsReceipt no matter what I have set it to on the client.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 6):

You need to make sure that your enum also has a DataContract, otherwise it will not be serialized, and each member must have the attribute EnumMember

```
[DataContract]
public enum TaskTypeEnum 
{ 
     [EnumMember] 
     GoodsReceipt, 

     [EnumMember] 
     ImportCosting 
}
```

Also see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347875.aspx

Comment: Thanks heaps for the suggestion Arcturus. Unfortunately the bloody thing still isn't working. I really don't know why. I have a project of unit tests that I'm using to run the web service. I've added the service as a "Web Reference" rather than a "Service Reference". Don't know if that's important.

Comment: If you add your attributes, make sure you update your service reference. It will not do that automatically.

Comment: Mark, are you developing for Windows 7 Phone? The [DataContractAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute.aspx) feature doesn't look like it is available for Window Mobile (pre .NET Framework 3.0).

Comment: Thanks again for the help Arcturus & jp2code. I've wasted too much time on this. I'll just have to pass a byte or something rather than an enum. I'll post an answer if I ever figure out what's going on here.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. In the proxy class fields of primitive types (i.e. non nullable fields) have a second field called Specified.

Perhaps in your case TaskContainer has a field called TaskTypeSpecified. Try setting

```
container.TaskTypeSpecified = true;
```